# Забавный вопрос об идентификаторах

Tags: c++, соревнование

Малому в универе досталась задача — написать компилируемую программу, в которой должен использоваться как можно в больших ипостасях, так сказать, один и тот же идентификатор. Но именно разных, так что какое-нибудь вложенное

```
namespace a { namespace a { namespace a {
```

ничего нового по сравнению с одним пространством имен не дает.

Поскольку малой уже сочинил и отправил

```
namespace a
{
    struct a
    {
        int a;
    };
    int a()
    {
        struct a a {0};
        return a.a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = a::a();
    std::cout << a;
}
```

считаю себя вправе задать эту задачку как вопрос — кто сможет добиться большего? :)

Comment: Макросов нет, не считается. А можно было бы ещё как минимум один набросить. Потом шаблон добавить, ещё плюс один. Это так сходу, не просыпаясь

Comment: @KoVadim Макросы - это неспортивно...

Comment: Вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: @KoVadim Шашечки. Ключевое слово — *идентификаторы*. В директивах препроцессора такого понятия нет...

Comment: то есть, `#define a bla-bla` не подходит? но может это преподавателю подойдет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос: другие идентификаторы допустимы? Или нужен только один?

Если допустимы, то вот развитие ответа Stanislav Volodarskiy:

```
template<typename a>
a aa(int*) {
    return a{};
    };

namespace a {
    struct a {
        int a;
        };

    int a(struct a a) {
        goto a;
        a:
        if (a.a) return a.a;
        else {
            struct a a {0};
            return a.a;
            }
        }
    }


int main() {
    int a = a::a(aa<struct a::a>(&a));
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: О других идентификаторах - не знаю, в принципе ничего сказано не было. А считать это разрешением или запретом?...

Answer (score 12):

Плюс метка, плюс аргумент функции, плюс атрибут (и даже три разных атрибута, один из которых с аргументом (!) ), плюс определение препроцессора:

```
#define a a

namespace a {
    struct a {
        int a;
    };

    int a(int a) {
        goto a;
    a:
        if (a) {
            return a;
        } else {
            struct a [[std::a, a::a(a), a]] a {0};
            return a.a;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int a = a::a(0);
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неплохо, неплохо :) Атрибуты — это за рамками ими изучавшегося (да откровенно, и за моими тоже... Кстати, VC++ пишет, что все атрибуты не распознаны). Но вот аргумент и метка — это да...